# getCount of Duplicates in List

Tags: c#, .net, list, count

I have this code:

```
public List<int> Duplicates(List<int> sequence)
{

    int[] countArr = new int[156];
    foreach (int i in sequence)
    {
        countArr[i]++;
    }

    List<int> resultList = new List<int>();

    for (var i = 0; i < countArr.Length; i++)
    {
        if (countArr[i] > 1)
        {
            resultList.Add(i);
        }
    }

    return resultList;
}
```

This is getting me the elements that are duplicated, but not how many times this elements are duplicated.

Thanks in advance for any help provided.

**EDIT**

I do not want to use LINQ

Comment: try `resultList.Count`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your algorithm already produces the required counts, so all you need to do is to arrange returning them to the caller in some way. One approach is to change the return type to `IList<KeyValuePair<int,int>>`. The collection of pairs you return would contain the number in the `Key` property, and its count in the `Value` property:

```
IList<KeyValuePair<int,int>> Duplicates(List<int> sequence) {
    var countArr = new int[156];
    foreach (int i in sequence) {
        countArr[i]++;
    }
    var resultList = new List<KeyValuePair<int,int>>();
    for (var i = 0; i < countArr.Length; i++) {
        if (countArr[i] > 1) {
            resultList.Add(new KeyValuePair<int,int>(i, countArr[i]));
        }
    }
    return resultList;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use GroupBy:

```
sequence.GroupBy(i => i).Select(g => new {Value = g.Key, Amount = g.Count()})
```

If you don't want to use Linq (why???) just collect value and amount together in a Tuple:

```
List<Tuple<int,int>> resultList = new List<Tuple<int,int>>();

for (var i = 0; i < countArr.Length; i++)
{
    if (countArr[i] > 1)
    {
        resultList.Add(Tuple.Create(i, countArr[i]));
    }
}
```

Comment: _"I do not want to use LINQ

"_

Comment: @TimSchmelter yes, haven't seen that edit as i wrote answer.

Answer (score 2):

That's a very complicated way you use, i'd rather return a `Dictionary<int, int>`:

```
public static Dictionary<int, int> Duplicates(IEnumerable<int> sequence)
{
    var duplicates = new Dictionary<int, int>();
    foreach (int i in sequence)
    {
        if(duplicates.ContainsKey(i))
            duplicates[i]++;
        else
            duplicates.Add(i, 1);
    }
    return duplicates;
}
```

Comment: Im trying to implement every answer given. But with this one i am getting the following error: 


KeyNotFoundException: The given key was not present in the dictionary.
System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.Int32,System.Int32].get_Item (Int32 key)

Comment: Not possible because i use ContainsKey. Are you sure you have used my code?

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer with dictionary:

```
void Main()
{
    List<int> intlist = new List<int>
    {
        1,
        1,
        1,
        2,
        2,
        3,
        4,
        4,
        4,
        4
    };


    var dict = new Dictionary<int, int>();
    foreach (var item in intlist)
    {
        if (!dict.ContainsKey(item)) // this checks for the existance of an item
        {
            dict.Add(item, 0); // this initialises the item in the dictionary
        }
        dict[item]++; // this will update the count of the item
    }

    // this is just for linqpad debug output and shows each value and their count
    // this can be achieved with foreach
    dict.Select(x => new { x.Key, x.Value}).Dump();
}
```

[image: Debug output]

Yes I know there is a `Select` at the bottom, but that has nothing to do with the duplicate collection.